# Is it possible to distinguish between DisplayFormat and EditFormat with Delphi LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, livebindings

I have an FMX TEdit, that is connected via LiveBindings to a `Currency` property of an object.

By default the value is displayed as `'12.34'`.

I know, I can [define my own functions for CustomFormat](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1226) for getting this displayed as `'12.34 €'`.

But if a user wants to edit this value in the control, I don't want him to struggle with the currency symbol. (Thus on entering the edit the control should display `'12.34'` again.)

Any idea how I can reach this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no support in LiveBindings/FireMonkey to differentiate between `DisplayFormat` and `EditFormat`.

I worked around the issue by placing the currency symbol outside the edit box.